# Executing sudo commands keep asking password although i've set visudo

Tags: ssh, sudo, rsync

I'm configuring remote deployment using rsync over ssh and there is need to execute a sudo command without password.

This is my visudo:

```bash
# Allow user to execute specified commands without password
Cmnd_Alias USER_SERVICES = /bin/systemctl reload nginx, /usr/sbin/nginx
-t
[user] ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:USER_SERVICES
```

With this setting i can confirm that specified commands can be executed manually(me typing these commands) without password prompt but whenever running that commands on script file like below it asks me the password.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

...
sudo systemctl reload nginx
...
```

How can i avoid password prompt in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two commands `systemctl reload nginx` and `/bin/systemctl reload nginx` are not identical.  The first depends on the directories included in the `PATH` environment variable, while the second one does not.

The `sudoers` files gives you the ability to use `/bin/systemctl reload nginx` so that is what you should use.